# How do I grab a number sandwiched between commas?

Tags: python, regex

The following are Python snippets

`line = '3520005,"Toronto (Ont.)",C  ,F,2503281,2481494,F,F,0.9,1040597,979330,630.1763,3972.4,1\r\n'` and I want to be able to get the first number sandwiched between two commas which in this case would be `,2503281,`

However, what I came up with doesn't seem to work properly: `m = re.search("\,([0-9])*\,",line)` only retains the last digit in the number.

Comment: I think you need to move the `*` inside the capture group, like: `",([0-9]*),"`

Comment: probably you should use the `csv` module because it may contain more `,` inside quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a non-regex solution:

```
>>> [item for item in line.split(',')[1:] if item.isdigit()][0]
'2503281'
```

Comment: The question doesn't specify, but bear in mind this only works for whole numbers, which not all numbers in this list are. Don't try and use this to pick out say the 3rd number, `0.9`, as you will get `1040597` instead

Answer (score 3):

The asterisk needs to go inside of the parentheses:

```
`",([0-9]*),"
```

Otherwise you only capture one of the digits.  You also don't need the backslashes before the commas, but that doesn't matter.

You may also want to use `+` instead of `*` to ensure that there is at least one digit, or even set a min/max limit on digits using `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned that using a regex for parsing comma separated values is fraught with oversights, fragility and potential errors. If you can coerce this into something the csv module can do -- you will be better off.

That said, this works:

```
import re

st='''line = '3520005,"Toronto (Ont.)",
C ,F,2503281,2481494,F,F,0.9,1040597,979330,630.1763,3972.4,1\r\n'''

print re.findall(r"(\d+\.?\d*)",st)
```

prints:

```
['3520005', '2503281', '2481494', '0.9', '1040597', '979330', '630.1763', '3972.4', '1']
```

[Here](http://www.regex101.com/r/gO8dR4) is the regex explanation.